# Не могу понять в чем проблема c CKEditor 5

Tags: python, html, django, ckeditor

````
Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Не логично. 

Когда из settings я удаляю строку CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/' у меня отображается CKEDITOR с некоторыми функциями (хоть и не со всеми что мне нужны) но стоит мне добавить строку KEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/' и CKEDITOR перестает отображаться на странице.
Кто то может сказать: удали просто строку и пусть отображается. Но. Во первых, мне не нравится что работает не логично и не правильно. Во вторых, static\ckeditor\build\ckeditor.js я разместил для того, что бы были функции(Разные шрифты, размеры и пр.)  которых сейчас нету.
дальше код в моих html, views,models…

у меня ckeditor в: 

D:\Сайт\ ..\static\ckeditor\package.json 

D:\Сайт\... \static\ckeditor\webpack.config.js 

D:\Сайт\ …\static\ckeditor\src 

D:\Сайт\... \static\ckeditor\sample 

D:\Сайт\... \static\ckeditor\build 

D:\Сайт\... \static\ckeditor\build\ckeditor.js

У меня в settings:

```…
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig',
    'users',
    'ckeditor',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'debug_toolbar',

]
…
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'catalog', 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main', 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/' #путь для загрузки файлов

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/catalog/ckeditor/' #путь к статическим файлам CKEditor```
В html:

 ```   {% extends 'main/base.html' %}

    {% load static %}

    {% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
    <div id="editor"></div>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.title.label_tag }}
            {{ form.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.content.label_tag }}
            {{ form.content }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.file.label_tag }}
            {{ form.file }}
        </div>

       
        <button type="submit">Загрузить</button>

    </form>

    {% endblock %}```
views:


```class ChapterDetail(DetailView):
    model = Chapter

    template_name = 'catalog/chapter_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'chapter'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        book_slug = self.kwargs.get('book_slug')
        chapter_slug = self.kwargs.get('chapter_slug')

        if book_slug is not None and chapter_slug is not None:
            return get_object_or_404(queryset, book__slug=book_slug, slug=chapter_slug)

        raise AttributeError("Book slug and chapter slug expected in the URL pattern")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm()  # add this line
        return context


class ChapterCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = Chapter
    form_class = ChapterForm
    template_name = 'catalog/chapter_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        book_slug = self.kwargs['book_slug']
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=book_slug)
        form.instance.book = book

        # If a file was uploaded
        if form.instance.file:
            try:
                # Read the file and put its content into the 'content' field
                file_content = form.instance.file.read().decode('utf-8')
                form.instance.content = file_content
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(self.request, f"Error reading file: {str(e)}")
                return super().form_invalid(form)
        elif not form.instance.content:
            messages.error(self.request, "You must provide chapter content or upload a file.")
            return super().form_invalid(form)

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        # test_func проверяет, выполняется ли условие для данного пользователя
        # Если пользователь в группе 'Перекладач', он может создать главу

        return self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Перекладач').exists()

    def get_success_url(self):
        book_slug = self.object.book.slug  # здесь мы получаем slug из созданной главы
        chapter_slug = self.object.slug
        return reverse('catalog:chapter_detail', kwargs={'book_slug': book_slug, 'chapter_slug': chapter_slug})```
forms:

```class ChapterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'file']

        help_texts = {
            'file': 'You can upload a text file instead of typing in the content.',
        }

models:
class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('catalog.Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_chapters')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = RichTextField(config_name='extends', blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='chapters/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


urls:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('catalog/', include(('catalog.urls', 'catalog'), namespace='catalog')),
    path('users/', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')) #текстовый редактор CKEditor
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)```
````

Comment: Отформатируйте вопрос **правильно**!